# Meaning of first "から" in "私からちゃんと話しとくから"

Tags: meaning, particle-から

Context of the sentence: A mother consoles a family member that complains about a third member of the family.

> 大丈夫。私**から**ちゃんと話しとくから。

I do realize that the sentence means something like "Don't worry. I'll have a serious talk with her." However, I do not understand the role of the first から.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This から is the same から that indicates origin or source, which often translates to the English word *from*.

Here 私から means 私 is the **initiator** of the action of "talking to her  properly".

In this case, on the surface level it may not be that much different from the subject marker が, and so the sentence can justly be translated to "I'll have a proper talk with her."